# Hibernate is not throwing LazyInitializationException in Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I work on a Spring Boot project with Hibernate 5.0. Unfortunately Hibernate reads the lazy initialized objects without throwing `LazyInitializationException` even after the transaction is committed. How can I enable the `LazyInitializationException` outside of transactions?

(The current behavior hides bugs in the code.)

Comment: Please give us some details; enable the showSql option and look at the queries issued by hibernate and see if the lazy fields are retrieved during the transaction.

Comment: are you sure that the lazy objects really are initialized?

Comment: Lazy-loading has got nothing to do with transactions but the lifecycle of the `EntityManager` which is kept open by default for the entire request (see the answer by Babtiste below). Can you elaborate on the "hides bugs" statement? Why is it a bug to be able to call a method that returns a proper result?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spring boot have a property `spring.jpa.open-in-view` with a default value of true. This will register a [OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html) that will keep the transaction alive for the entire request.

try adding this to your application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

[A discussion about it on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7107)

[Some documentation about Spring Boot properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Hope it helped!