# Spring REST controller and Hibernate Session lifetime

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jackson, lazy-initialization

Suppose I have class `A` and `B` with one-to-one association from `A` to `B`.

```
@Entity
class A {
    @Id Long id;
    @OneToOne(fetch = LAZY) B b;
    // getters, setters
}

@Entity
class B {
    @Id Long id;
}
```

Using Spring JPA, I have a repository for `A` as follows

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {
    A findById(Long id);
    void delete(Long id);
}
```

Finally, a REST controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/a")
class AController {
    @Autowired ARepository repo;

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public A getA(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return repo.findById(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    public A deleteA(@PathVariable Long id) {
        A a = repo.findById(id);
        repo.delete(id);
        return a;
    }
}
```

### Problem

Suppose I have saved an instance of `A` with `id = 1` into the database, when I send a GET request to `/a/1`, it returns a JSON representation of `A` with no problem.

But when I tried to delete the instance by sending a DELETE request to `/a/1`, I got `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException` with following root cause

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session

### Question

My understanding is, this error occurred because Jackson was trying to serialize the instance by call `a.getB()` after the completion of method `deleteA()` in which the lifetime of Hibernate session has ended, is this correct?

If so, I don't understand why this error doesn't occur in method `getA()`, I think Hibernate session should end immediately after the completion of `repo.findById(id);`, right?

Comment: Are you using spring boot for your controller?

Comment: `I don't understand why this error doesn't occur in method getA()`, (if you're using Spring Boot), you'll find the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877337/hibernate-is-not-throwing-lazyinitializationexception-in-spring-boot-project). For your first question , and AFAIK, you should not have `LazyInitializationException` in your `deleteA(Long)` method, as `Session` will be used to fetch `B` data similar to `getA()` method.

Comment: @O.Badr, thanks for answer. I use Spring Boot. I followed the link you suggest and try setting the `open-in-view` to false, then method `getA()` become giving the error. But when I set `open-in-view` to true, `getA()` doesn't give error, but `deleteA()` does. I have tried deleting `repo.delete(id);` from `deleteA()` and it become working. So I suspect this might be related to the `repo.delete(id);` method?

Comment: I've tested your code, and `deleteA()` works without any exception, which spring boot version are you using? try to not return `a` object in your `deleteA()` mehod (return  [ResponseEnity](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) with and `HttpStatus` instead, e.g. `ResponseEntity.ok()` )?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely related to Jackson trying to initialize `A.b` for serialization.

Even if you enable `open-in-view`, the error will persist, because you're trying to initialize a field of an entity that no longer exists.

If `A.b` should indeed be lazily fetched, consider using `@JsonIgnore` as well (if, on the other hand, `A.b` should be serialized and sent in the response body together with `A`, there's no point in making it lazily fetched, just use the default `FetchType.EAGER`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't like `open-in-view` because I feel it's a lie, you should know how you're accessing the database and not have unexpected accesses after the initial transaction.

I also don't like using `FetchType.EAGER` for everything for the same reason, you should know how you're accessing the database. `FetchType.EAGER` may lead to joins that you don't expect.

A possible solution here is to make specific methods in your repository and annotate them with named graphs. E.g.

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "A.fetchB",attributeNodes=@NamedAttributeNode("b"))
public class A implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id Long id;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) B b;
    // getters, setters
}
```

and

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {
    @EntityGraph(value="A.fetchB", type=EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    A findAFetchBById(Long id);
}
```

then

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/a")
public class AController {
    @Autowired 
    private ARepository repo;

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public A getA(@PathVariable Long id) {
        A a = repo.findAFetchBById(id);
        return a;
    }

    @Transactional
    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    public A deleteA(@PathVariable Long id) {
        A a = getA(id);
        repo.delete(id);
        return a;
    }
}
```

This way you know what your doing with the database. This will result in a single optimized query instead of multiple queries that get executed when you access the various children of an `Entity`.